# Set values in a casted object Swift

Tags: swift, casting, save

I have a protocol `Food` which contains a name and a price.

The  struct `Fruit` is implementing this protocol and has another specific variable named `color`.

A class `Fridge` (my ViewController) can contain every type of food, so the datatype of the variable `food` is `Food`.

In the first step, I set the `food` variable to a new `Fruit`.

```
fridge.food = Fruit(name: "Apple", price: 0.99, color: "Yellow")
```

Then in my VC `Fridge` I want to modify the fruits color with the following code:

```
var fruit = fridge.food as! Fruit
fruit.color = "Red"
```

Later, when I want to retrieve the information it returns "Yellow":

```
var fruit = fridge.food as! Fruit
print(fruit.color)
//prints Yellow
```

Now the question is how I can correctly change the value of that castet object?

Comment: Are you sure those are classes and not structs?

Comment: Using structs or classes with `var`s, it works as expected. Is there a place you might be reassigning it or maybe not triggering the change?

Answer (score 1):

Current code look like this.

```
protocol Food {
    var name : String {set get}
    var price : Double {set get}
}

struct Fruit : Food {
    var name : String
    var price : Double
    var color : String
}

class Fridge {
    var food : Fruit
    init(food : Fruit) {
       self.food = food
    }
}

class Container {
    var food : Fruit
    init(food : Fruit) {
        self.food = food
    }
}


var container = Container.init(food: Fruit(name: "Apple", price: 0.99, color: "Yellow"))
var fridge = Fridge.init(food:container.food)
var fruit = fridge.food as! Fruit
fruit.color = "Red"
print(fruit.color) // "Red"

var fruit1 = fridge.food as! Fruit
print(fruit1.color) // "Yellow"
```

**because Fruit is struct type and struct is value type not reference type**

```
var fruit = fridge.food as! Fruit // it will create a new reference instead of modified the created one.
fruit.color = "Red" 
print(fruit.color) //"Red"
```

**Solution :**

```
var fridge = Fridge.init(food: container.food)
fridge.food.color = "Red"
print(fridge.food.color) // "Red"
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if they are classes then it is not possible. to print Yellow instead of red

Comment: Yes it does looks strange

Comment: I checked your answer but the datatype of `food` in `Fridge` is `Food` not `Fruit`. (I also updated my question for more clarity).

Comment: still food is the type of Fruit not Fridge,  `fridge.food = Fruit(name: "Apple", price: 0.99, color: "Yellow")` , first correct your question

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit{
    var name:String
    var price: Double
    var color:String
    init(name:String,price:Double,color:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

Then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fruit = Fruit(name: "Apple", price: 0.99, color: "Yellow")
    print(fruit.color)// Prints Yellow
    fruit.color = "RED"
    print(fruit.color) //Prints RED
}
```

Comment: You missed a central part of the question here, to access the fruit object via the Fridge object. I am sure OP know how to change a property ;)

Comment: That is not relevant to your answer as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to cast with optional as?, because otherwise you've got a crash in the case of other type.

Here is correct approach:

```
protocol Food {
    var name : String {set get}
    var price : Double {set get}
}

struct Fruit : Food {
    var name : String
    var price : Double
    var color : String
}

class Fridge {
    var food : Food
    init(food : Fruit) {
       self.food = food
    }
}


var fridge = Fridge.init(food: Fruit(name: "Apple", price: 0.99, color: "Yellow"))

print(fridge.food.name) // "Apple"
if let food = fridge.food as? Fruit {
    print(food.color) // "Yellow"
}

if var fruit = fridge.food as? Fruit {
    fruit.color = "Red"
    fridge.food = fruit
}
if let food = fridge.food as? Fruit {
    print(food.color) // "Red"
}
```